# How to work with adf task flow opening as pop up using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am trying to automate a pop up in an application developed using **ADF JDeveloper 11.1.2.4.0**.

1. In our application, we are using a `region which display 3 task flows`. One of the taskflow has a fragment A.jsff.
2. This fragment has a button which in-turn opens another taskflow (having page B.jspx) as popup.
3. My problem is I am not able to hook with the objects in the pop up window. I have tried swithTo() method, but still no solution.

Please help me out.

Comment: please put whatever u have done so far

Comment: Things tried so far:
1. Checked if the pop up opened has different windowid, so that if there are multiple windows, will switch control to the pop up.
 Result: driver.getWindowHandles() returns only one window i.e., the parent window. NO SOLUTION.
2. Tried finding the frame and then hooking to objects in the pop up. Like
 WebElement frameID = driver.findElement(By.Css("#xxxx>iframe"));
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameID);
 driver.findElement(By.id("yyyy")).click(); 
 Result: NO SOLUTION

Comment: 3. Checked with Selenium IDE if all the steps are recorded.
 Observation: Steps till clicking on the button are recorded. But after that Selenium IDE fails to record any operation done on the pop up.

Comment: @Killer R  I have mentioned all the things tried so far...any help